# Is it possible to change only the color of text shadow?

Tags: fonts, css

I have 9 differently colored buttons (red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, pink, off-white and slate) and I was wondering if it was possible to manipulate and alter only the color of the `text-shadow` CSS property for these buttons, while keeping the other values the same?

For example, I have two different classes; one is for buttons with 11px font size and the other is for 14px font size (standard across my website):

```
.button-11 {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border-width: 0.09091em;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 0 0.90909em;
    text-shadow: 0.09091em 0.09091em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -0.09091em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -0.09091em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 -0.09091em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
}

.button-14 {
    border-width: 0.07143em;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 0 0.71429em;
    text-shadow: 0.07143em 0.07143em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -0.07143em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -0.07143em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 -0.07143em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
}
```

For those unaware, I have two separate classes because each font size requires different values for the borders and text shadow, since I'm using the em measurement - 0.09em equates to 1px at font size 11px, and 0.07em equates to 1px at font size 14px.

So, in order to cut down on the CSS file size, it would help greatly if I could simply change the color of the `text-shadow` CSS properties without having to include the other values.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Sun, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ECSxc/) is an extract on JSFiddle. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, this can be accomplished using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)!**

As others have pointed out, an official `text-shadow-color` property does not exist. However, CSS will let you create your own "custom property"—aka CSS variable—and use it in your button's CSS.

Let's create a variable called `--my-shadow-color`. Any name will do, but it must start with `--`.

#### Create a CSS variable

To make it globally available so you can use it as a default, put it inside the special `:root` selector:

```css
:root {
  --my-shadow-color: gray;
}

button {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px var(--my-shadow-color);
}
```

The shadow will now be gray by default. But you can override it for each different button class. Note that you can define (or redefine) CSS variables inside any selector—`:root` is just the most general. As with regular CSS properties, more specific selectors will trump less specific ones.

#### Override the variable for different selectors

You can now override the color for any specific selector. Let's create classes of `.button-red` and `.button-blue` to set the text-shadow color for our different buttons.

```css
.button-blue {
  --my-shadow-color: blue;
}
.button-red {
  --my-shadow-color: red;
}
```

We can now control our shadow color by using the `.button-blue` and `.button-red` classes in our HTML:

```html
<button class="button-blue">Blue</button>
<!-- ^ shadow will be blue -->

<button class="button-red">Red</button>
<!-- ^ shadow will be red -->

<button>Default</button>
<!-- ^ shadow will be gray -->
```

Comment: As this question is now over eight years old (insane), I will update the accepted answer to yours as things have changed dramatically. According to Can I Use..., CSS variables are supported by enough browsers to cover 93.3% of users without issue, and so I believe that this solution should be the correct way to go for modern development choices (providing you don't need to support IE 11 for whatever reason). Thank you for this answer, by the way. That hadn't crossed my mind! :)

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, no: it seems ([according to the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-shadow)) that there is no `box-shadow-color` property.

The above left intact, though it was addressing the wrong properties; to address the *question*, though it seems that the same point is true of the `text-shadow` property, with the `text-shadow-color` similarly unsupported (and [non-existent in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-shadow-property)).

Comment: Hi David, I was referring to `text-shadow` and not `box-shadow` :)

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I feel something like this would help greatly to save bandwidth for mobile devices and slower internet connections. It will save people having to declare the entire property. For the shadow measurements, an additional 'inherit' value could be used.

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help, though I'm sorry the answer isn't the one you want. And I tend to agree with you, I was surprised that neither of the properties exist.

Answer (score 0):

If your text-shadow color is the same as the text color you could do this:

```
.button-red {
    color: #ff0000;
}    
.button-11 {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border-width: 0.09091em;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 0 0.90909em;
    text-shadow: 0.09091em 0.09091em 0 rgba(currentcolor, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -0.09091em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -0.09091em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 -0.09091em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
}
.button-14 {
    border-width: 0.07143em;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 0 0.71429em;
    text-shadow: 0.07143em 0.07143em 0 rgba(currentcolor, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -0.07143em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -0.07143em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 -0.07143em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
}
```

And then on the button

```
<button class="button-red button-11">…</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Is it possible to change the color of text shadow, see the below links.

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow.en.html

http://css3gen.com/text-shadow/

Comment: This was not what the OP was talking about; the problem is when you have a dozen text shadows it's really a PITA (and/or ugly) to redefine them all (and sizes/position) just because you need to change their colors.

Answer (score -2):

Text shadow and Box shadow both can be set

**Text Shadow Example**

```
h1
{
    text-shadow:2px 2px #FF0000;
}
```

**Box Shadow Example**

```
div
{
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ff0000; /* Red Color Shadow */
}
```

Is this what are you expecting [Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/6FQcq/). You can control the shadow fall distance.

Comment: Hi Sun, I appreciate your input, but unfortunately that isn't what I was referring to. I'm aware of the options that `text-shadow` gives you, but what I was asking, was if the `text-shadow` property had any sort of method to set only the color in its values, while inheriting the positioning values from another class? For example: `text-shadow: 0.09091em 0.09091em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);` - from this, I would be asking if it was possible to simply set `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` as a `text-shadow` value...

Comment: ... while leaving the px/em values before it, out (so they could inherit from another class assigned to the button). If you like, something that operates like `text-shadow-color`? From the sounds of it, it doesn't look possible.

Comment: I got you. But this is not possible h-shadow and v-shadow field are require(mandatory) field.So you should set the fall distnace.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I guess the additional data isn't really a problem since most websites usually require a lot of external resources to be loaded in the headers. Thank you for your time. :)